How to make iOS App language setting always appear?
In my iOS app I want to implement system per-app language setting.
Unfortunately this setting won’t appear until user has only one preferred language selected in system. This behavior is very unexpected and is misleading to users of my app that want to change app language. Is it possible to make this setting always appear?

I received answer from Apple team that this is possible by adding UIPrefersShowingLanguageSettings with value Yes to Info.plist. I checked and it works
